# Walk mode throws me upwards!

Tags: mesh, objects, image

I have added a large (approx half a mile square) Empty:Image object to use as a semi-transparent reference image and have a Mesh:Plane just below it. I would like to be able to walk on this Mesh to work on it. Whenever I think I'm on top of the Mesh and enter Walk mode it violently throws me upwards and the objects disappear into the distance! can anyone offer a suggestion on what might be going on? I have tried switching and disabling gravity with no effect. If I reload Blender walk mode works fine.

Thanks.
Andrew.

Comment: When you say walk mode are you referring to the **Shift + F** walk mode? I tried it over a plane and empty image, then hit **Tab** to enable gravity and I had no trouble.

Comment: It will be good if you provide a screenshot or GIF for it, so that we can understand the scenario better